# WifiManager and ConnectivityManager support in Arc Welder

Tags: android

I am using the welder to run my application apk and it looks very fine at the beginning however i realized that some features like WifiManager and ConnectivityManager doesn't work correctly.

For example, Below function always return True regardless of running system of welder's actual connection status and network status change broadcast is not kicked in.
To guarantee my app to work correctly, i need to have these kind of functionalities.

Are these known issue then is it going to be fixed soon ?
Any comment welcomed.

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager mngr = (ConnectivityManager) InRestoWaitApplication.getInstance()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = mngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null
            || !mngr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
        return false;

    return true;
}

public static boolean isWifiEnabled() {

    WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager)InRestoWaitApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wfMgr.isWifiEnabled();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and make a class like ***NetworkAvailablity.java***

```
public class NetworkAvailablity {

public static boolean checkNetworkStatus(Context context) {
    boolean HaveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean HaveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                HaveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                HaveConnectedMobile = true;
    }

    return HaveConnectedWifi || HaveConnectedMobile;
   }
 }
```

And in the your code use these following lines which ***check that internet is available or not***

```
 if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(getActivity())) {
         //code here 
    }
    else
    {
    // give message here by Toast or create the alert dilog 
         Toast.makeText(context, "No network is available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```